# java thread.stop() почему deprecated

Tags: java, concurrency

перевод документации не сделал сабж понятнее для меня:

> Потому что это по своей сути небезопасно. Это приводит к разблокировке всех залоченных мониторов (исключение ThreadDeath пробрасывается вверх по стеку). Если любой из объектов, ранее защищенный мониторами, был в неустойчивом состоянии, таким его теперь могут увидеть другие потоки. Это может привести к неопределённому поведению, как скрытому труднообнаружимому, так и ярковыраженному. В отличие от других unchecked-исключений, ThreadDeath убивает потоки молча, так что пользователь может и не узнать, что его программа, вероятно, повреждена. Повреждение может проявиться в любое время после реальной аварии, через несколько часов или даже дней.

Можете привести пример, когда вызов этого метода действительно небезопасен?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да все очень просто. Так как stop останавливает поток там, где его найдет, то и результат соотвествующий. К примеру, поток может залочить мютекс и начать выполнять свои действия. А тут его убивают. Мютекс остается залоченым. А раз есть мютекс, значит его использует ещё кто то (в нормально написанном коде). И этот кто то не сможет залочить мютекс.

Пример ещё. Многие данные должны быть "консистенты". То есть, согласованными. Если поток прервать, то нет никакой гарантии, в каком именно состоянии будет система. Даже по коду угадать сложно. Все дело в том, что компилятор может переставлять некоторые инструкции для качественной оптимизации.

А теперь представьте, что это кардиостимулятор или комплекс по управлению полетами самолетов...

Comment: а Interrput() бросает исключения которые сразу видны, ок

Comment: да, в том и плюс - исключение можно обработать, корректно закрыть ресурсы (отсутствие в java деструкторов не освобождает от отвественности за открытые ресурсы).

В POSIX thread пошли дальше - там есть "безопасные точки" и "план отката". Если тред послали сигнал прерваться, то он это сделает на безопасной точке и выполнит набор функций для отката блокировок и освобождению ресурсов (но это на совести программиста).